# How do I revoke JWT everytime a new token generated using django-graphql-jwt?

Tags: django, graphql, jwt, graphene-python, graphene-django

I am using django-graphql-jwt (https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/latest/index.html) to handle authentication for my Django Python Graphene application. Currently, everytime a new JWT generated, the previous JWT is still active as long as it does not pass its expiry time.

I want to revoke/prevent access to previously generated JWT (even if the JWT is not expired yet) whenever I generate a new JWT.

What I am thinking is utilizing the origIat inside the JWT payload and comparing it with something like a last_login attribute from the User model. I noticed though, that User.last_login is not updated whenever I am authenticating using JWT.

Still finding how to do this problem properly and wondering if there is any of you already solving this problem before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution:

1. Add last_jwt_iat field to User model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    last_jwt_iat = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email}'
```

2. Subclassing graphql_jwt.relay.JSONWebTokenMutation, and update User.last_jwt_iat whenever new token is requested

```
class ObtainJSONWebToken(graphql_jwt.relay.JSONWebTokenMutation):

    @classmethod
    def resolve(cls, root, info, **kwargs):
        # Update User.last_jwt_iat by generating current UTC timestamp
        # Probably better if we can extract the origIat from GraphQL payload
        user = info.context.user
        last_jwt_iat = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        user.last_jwt_iat = last_jwt_iat
        user.save()
        return cls()
```

3. Use Graphene middleware to check if User.last_jwt_iat > current JWT's iat

```
def _authenticate(request):
    """
    Check if user is anonymous and JWT authorization header exist
    :param request: HttpRequest instance
    :return: Boolean
    """
    is_anonymous = not hasattr(request, 'user') or request.user.is_anonymous
    return is_anonymous and get_http_authorization(request) is not None


class AuthCheckIat(object):
    def resolve(self, next, root, info, **args):
        context = info.context
        # Check if User.last_jwt_iat > token iat, raise error, stop evaluation
        if _authenticate(context):
            jwt_decoded = jwt_decode(get_http_authorization(context))
            username = jwt_decoded['username']
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            iat = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(jwt_decoded['origIat'], tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
            if user.last_jwt_iat > iat:
                raise PermissionDenied(
                    'User last JWT issued time is greater than supplied JWT issued time. Please use newer token. ')
        return next(root, info, **args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from graphql_jwt.refresh_token.models import RefreshToken


@receiver(post_save, sender=RefreshToken)
def clear_tokens(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    recent_issued_token = instance
    try:
        token_user = RefreshToken.objects.get(token=recent_issued_token).user
        user_all_tokens = RefreshToken.objects.filter(user=token_user)
        tokens_length = len(user_all_tokens)
        if tokens_length > 1:
            tokens_to_delete = user_all_tokens[0:tokens_length - 1]
            for token in tokens_to_delete:
                token.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error deleting existing tokens')
```